# How to configure EC2 instance to accept inbound traffic from Bitbucket using reverse DNS

Tags: networking, dns, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to configure an EC2 instance to accept any incoming traffic originating from Bitbucket (bitbucket.org, api.bitbucket.org, etc). 
I tried this:

[image]

But it gave me the error pictured in the red box.

Comment: for example, I want to allow these IPs, but the IPs can/will change https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall-343343385.html

Comment: I dont think you can attack the problem this way.(this is one of the hard issues of networking - particularly in the cloud). I believe that Amazon use software defined networks that require IP ranges - which is reasonable as reverse DNS kills network performance. My guess is you will hsve to allow all traffic on the relevant ports into your EC2 instance and run your own firewall - presumably using a script which runs periodically as you will run into the same issues - You will.most likely find domain names resolve only once when the script runs

Comment: Ok so maybe create our own server that does the reverse DNS? and then whitelist our server with AWS? Since we know our server's IP, that won't change.

Comment: That doesnt make sense to me.  The problem is not the nameserver IP changing, its the content of the DNS to IP mapping changing and the load and latency that this lookup causes on checking for each packet.

Comment: Yeah I don't know enough about networking to follow. All I can say is that we might know the traffic is coming from bitbucket.org, but we don't which IPs as those could change. If we had some reverse dns we could look at an incoming request, get the IP and make sure it resolves to bitbucket.org?

Comment: Correct, but the big question is how do you do the reverse DNS in real time.

Comment: Well that's where my networking knowledge falls short, but I thought you could do reverse dns in a few seconds? Not hard real time but soft real time? These are for devops tools, so a few seconds delay is no big deal.

Comment: Node.js has a  utility is `dns.reverse()` - https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_reverse_ip_callback

Comment: Yes, if you kick the problem back to the application level it becomes trivial to do reverse DNS. Unfortunately this does.not work well at a firewall (ie packet) level. There are also some minor security concerns if someone can intercept and modify the reverse DNS queries or if Bitbucket forget to update reverse DNS - which may not be a problem here.

Comment: alright so if I do thing with a middleman server, I can do the reverse dns - is security still an issue with https?

Comment: Im not sure how a middleman server would help, nor what you are trying to achieve. After googling Bitbucket it seems that it is a versioning service (ie git repo + bits)  If your vms are clients of bitbucket why do you need to bother with thus, rather then allowing all outbound port 443 requests (and related return traffic)? Forgive me for saying this but based on your questions I dont think you can get more then a modicum of security in your system without engaging an expert.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94471/discussion-between-davidgo-and-alexander-mills).

Comment: Bitbucket HTTP POSTs to our server, we need to accept incoming traffic from Bitbucket

Comment: Looking at the bitbucket URL you presented I think the expected solution is for you to whitelist their given IP ranges and additionally set up some kind of monitoring for that page - as if it changes they state they will update that page.  Its likely that this is a "cover themselves thing" as static IP addresses don't change very often - but might in an emergency or migrating to other providers.

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall-343343385.html and https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/

> Using SSH to commit from behind a corporate firewall may require your network administrator to make specific network configuration changes to permit SSH connectivity from your computer to Bitbucket.
>
> You can use these IP ranges to whitelist requests made from your build environments.

You will need multiple rules to achieve this as only one CIDR block can be added in a rule.

These IPs will probably not change so often so as to create a problem for you. Bitbucket would take care of that.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.